# Android Studio Jetpack compose Auto imports are not working anymore

Tags: android-studio

I've started today with Android Jetpack Compose. At the beginning it worked all fine. On some classes you just have to watch that you get the right package. But on some Point I've messed something up an I don't know what. I've just wanted to Import a package and then some context menu popped up, I accidentally pressed 'Ok' and since then the "Import" doesn't show up anymore when I write a class from a compose package.

[image: On other classes it works fine]

[image: On the Jetpack classes it does not work anymore]

There is surely an option I've turned off but I don't know what. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

Go to file > Settings in Android Studio then search in the settings for "imports".

Under editor click Auto Import and scroll down to the bottom.

The check the two boxes for Kotlin as shown here:

[image: screenshot].

Comment: This is not always the best thing to do as Andriod Studio has the tendency to import the wrong package. This makes it very hard to debug and figure out what is going on.